# What authentication should I use to connect my app to Google Drive via API

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-drive-api

1. I would like to connect my application directly with Google Drive API and i do not know what authentication should I use. Main idea is to my application will generate files and then will send these files to Google Drive to share folder in workspace. Only my application will connect to google drive via Api. The file will be sent to a shared drive (for which I will be able to grant rights to other users (not only in the same organization), but this will be done directly in the google drive application), where people with access will be able to view or download files (directly in the google drive application).
   I'm thinking of using Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications, but I'm not sure if this is the correct solution. Please help me with this.
2. should the files be sent individually or can they be sent in batches? How better to do it?
3. is it possible to upload files to google drive via API that are password encrypted?
   Thank you!